# getting error in passenger

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, passenger

```
cannot load such file -- rack (LoadError)
  /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
  /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/passenger-5.0.14/lib/phusion_passenger/loader_shared_helpers.rb:395:in `activate_gem'
  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/passenger-5.0.14/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:101:in `preload_app'
  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/passenger-5.0.14/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:153:in `<module:App>'
  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/passenger-5.0.14/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:29:in `<module:PhusionPassenger>'
  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/passenger-5.0.14/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:28:in `<main>'
```

Answer (score -1):

It seems like the `rake` gem is not installed. If you are using `Bundler`, make sure the `rake` gem is listed in the `Gemfile`

```
gem 'rake'
```

Install the gem running

```
$ bundle
```

You can also install the gem directly using

```
$ gem install rake
```

however, as you have a Rails project, the correct way is to add it in the `Gemfile` and install it via `Bundler`.

Comment: I have installed the rake but getting same error ..!!

Comment: You probably installed it in a different RVM gemset or version, as Passenger is clearly unable to find it.